# How can I tell whether a page was generated by JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Since there are many programming languages that can be used to develop a web application.  Without looking at the source code, what are some ways to identify that a web application was written in Java?

Comment: The term "web application" is pretty non-specific.  Can you clarify?  Do you mean just HTML, a server side application, or something else?

Comment: To clarify both html, a server side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Websites using Java EE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983575/websites-using-java-ee)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can findout it, the URL can like .jsp, .jspx, .do, .action, .zul/.zhtml(zk framework) and even no extension such as /servlet/http-header-test.

A posible way (should not rely on it too) is check the `Server` http-header of response, the following example is a response returned by `Tomcat` server:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"7777-1302152739000"
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Apr 2011 05:05:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 7777
Date: Wed, 04 May 2011 19:47:23 GMT
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably a `.jsp` extension on the URL.

However, this doesn't necessarily imply it is a JavaServer Pages script (e.g. I could set .jsp files to render using PHP on a server), nor does every JSP page have a `.jsp` extension (I could make .html render using JSP on my server if I liked, or even hide the extensions on pages).

Answer (score 4):

Most of the times there are a few hints but  essentially the web servers serve html markup so it could be configured to hide the server side stuff. So there can be no definitive way of telling that a site was written in java.

Answer (score 1):

Check the URL. If the pages end in .jsp, it's a Java Server page. Also, examine the response headers on your page request. There may be an X-Powered-By header or something similar that says it's powered by java.

Comment: The extension is the least reliable way to check for the language. These days with MVC apps all the rage is to use RESTful urls so the name of the page that you are loading is not always present in the url. Most PHP frameworks such as Kohana hides the extension. Look at the URLs of SO, what language did they use? Spring MVC same thing.

Comment: Of course. But it is one way to check. There's not really anyone who would want to fake a Java page, so seeing .jsp is a pretty reliable way to find out a page runs Java, which is what OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

If the URL contains an extension, see if that extension is .jsp, .jsf or .jspx. It's possible to hide that, but if it has one of those extensions it's a pretty sure bet that it's written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The Struts library likes to (used to?) use .do extensions.